# Does IP address identify or locate a host?

Tags: ip-address

Some books say IP address is used to identify the host. Some YouTube videos say that IP address is used to locate the device. It tells us which network the device is located at but it is the mac address that identifies the device

Does IP address locate the device? Or does it identify the device? From what I know, the IP address can change. Only mac address is fixed.

Comment: An IP or MAC address *may be used* to identify a device. Strictly speaking, they just identify an *interface*. 'Identify a device/interface' also has several perspectives, from application layer (FQDN) to network layer (IP address) to link layer (MAC address).

Answer (score 5):

Both can be true because they are identifying the host at different network layers.

Remember that not all data-link protocols use MAC addressing. The data-link protocol may use addressing to identify a host on a LAN (not all data-link protocols even have addressing; PPP only links two devices, so there is no need for an address because any frame is destined to the only other host on the LAN). Data-link protocols encapsulate the network layer packets inside data-link frames.

IP addressing identifies a device at the network layer, and it is also used to route packets between networks to a distant host. The packets that travel between networks will be encapsulated and decapsulated with the various data-link protocols in between the source and destination hosts. Not all packets are destined for a distant host, and they can identify a host on the LAN, but either way, the packets get encapsulated inside frames for delivery on the LAN.

Comment: both **is** true.

Comment: Sorry @Effie, *both* is a plural indefinite pronoun.  So *are* is correct.

Comment: @Effie, I wrote **_can_** because not all data-link protocols use MAC addressing. On a data-link protocols that uses MAC addressing, both **_are_** true, but with something like frame relay or ATM, there is no MAC addressing, so both **_are not_** true because there is no MAC addressing.

Comment: IP is identifier because (almost?) all transport protocols treat is as such. Internet checksum in transport layer is calculated over IP addresses. IP address is both an identifier and a locator, which is written in almost every resource about either mobile IP or any identifier/locator separation protocol e.g., LISP. Data-link layer identifier or absence thereof is pretty irrelevant for this question.

Comment: Can I ask another question? is it correct to say that the IP address is like mailing address of a house and the mac address is like the social security number of a person living inside the house? not sure if this is the correct analogy.

Comment: Not a good analogy.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIiQiw7fpsU&t=190s  https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-IP-address-and-MAC-address-and-how-they-are-used

Comment: Well, if it is on the Internet, it must be true - not.

Comment: sorry, this video is really bad. you need to understand the concept of local networks, aka layer 2, and Internet(working) aka layer 3 which connects different local networks into Internet. Each local network can have its own addressing scheme, which is used to forward packets between devices on the same network. Internet interconnects all local networks into one global network. This global network uses its own addressing scheme, the IP addresses, each of which identifies a device, connected to the network.

Comment: the interplay of layer(s) 2 and layer 3 in Internet is a fundamental concept. Without it, explaining IP addresses and MAC addresses (or any other address) is impossible.

Comment: PPP does have a "MAC" address, it is one byte long and usually negotiated away at the beginning, as both sides use `0xff` (the broadcast address) anyway. It is however possible to use PPP on a multidrop bus, such as RS485, with multiple stations.

Comment: @WorldTreeBoy SSN is a very poor analogy for MAC address because MAC address is merely required to be unique in their immediate network, and can be changed manually, or even automatically for privacy reasons. Outside the immediate network, it's never transferred or used, you can't send a packet to devices outside your immediate network merely from a MAC address, all you can use is IP and port, it's up to the routers to manage which port is forwarded to which device on what port. The IP addresses themselves can change very quickly, so mailing address is also a rather inaccurate analogy.

Comment: actually the biggest problem in this analogy is that IP addresses also identify concrete person in the house. So, similar analogy, mail in organization. Each brief has a Name/Address aka (IP) of a very concrete person in this organization. The global post service (layer3) is however delivering mail to the internal post service of the organization. This internal post service (layer2) then looks up the person using some kind of organization-internal ID (MAC) and determines how to deliver mail to this particular person.

Comment: The mail still has name of the person, so noone  else is allowed to open the brief. What changes is the delivery mechanism, i.e., how the internal post service finds the particular person.

Answer (score 0):

> so my question is does ip address locate the device or does it identifies the device because from what i know the ip address can change and only mac address is fixed

Adding a bit about IP as an identifier… in some cases IP subnets can be duplicated in different routing tables or VRFs… as such IP isn’t a good identifier.  Use [dot1x](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1X) if you need to establish identity…. Mac addresses / IP addresses can easily be spoofed if you are not requiring bidirectional traffic in the identification process.